# JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwriteの高速化を行いたい

Tags: json, unity2d

Unityで開発しております。
Jsonファイルを使用してデータの保存・読み込みを行っております。

こちらデータ量がかなり多くなり、ファイルサイズが110MBほどになっており、
これを

```
data = new HogeData();
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite( jsonFile, data );
```

といったUnityの基本的な形での変換処理で読み込みを行っております。
ファイルサイズが大きいためこの処理だけで2.7秒ほどかかっており、
読み込み時間を早くしたいと考えております。
IDによって参照先のJsonファイルを切り替えていくプロジェクトなため読み込み処理を呼び出すタイミングが多く、
部分読み込みや非同期による読み込みが出来ればと考えております。

何か方法などありますでしょうか。

Comment: もし読み込みや保存(反映)処理が多いのであれば、
起動時に時間はかかりますが、全てdataとして読み出してメモリで操作する方が効率的だと思います。いかがでしょうか。今後もデータが増加し、メモリの制約もあるのであれば、ファイル入出力よりもDB(ファイルベースのSQLite以外)の方が高速に動作しやすいと思います。

Comment: SQLiteの使用も考えていたのですが、こちらJsonでの取り扱いとほぼ変わらないのでしょうか。他Unityで使用できるDBでは何かおすすめの物はございますでしょうか。

Comment: 正直110MB程度であれば共通アクセスできる変数(インスタンス)を用意してしまった方が、今後DBへの移行も難しくなく、実装も簡単で高速に動くと思われます。1GB程度であればDBの導入をご検討ください。またDBについてですが、SQLiteは実体がファイルなので、上記のようなJsonでの取り扱いとほぼ変わらないか、クエリの発行でかえって実行速度が落ちる可能性もあります。データベースとしてはMySQLの記事が沢山あるので導入は簡単かもしれませんが、作成しているゲームの配布を前提とするならPostgreSQLがおすすめです。